# Replace the existing data in CSV file using php or CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

If  `a` in php is to `write` at the `end of file` and `w` is to `write` at the `beginning of file`

What if I want to edit the existing data in csv file and the location of the data is in the middle row. What should i use to update the existing data or edit it?

below is my code in controller and view.. What i need to know now is **the Edit and Delete that will automatically update into CSV file**. Thank you in advance for the help :)

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Datacast_ctr extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $this->load->helper('csv');
    }

    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->library('csvreader');

       $filePath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv';

       $data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);

       $this->load->view('datacast_view', $data);
    }

    function write_csv()
    {
        $R1 = $this->input->post('val1');
        $R2 = $this->input->post('val2');
        $R3 = $this->input->post('val3');
        $H1 = $this->input->post('valh1');
        $R4 = $this->input->post('val4');
        $R5 = $this->input->post('val5');
        $H2 = $this->input->post('valh2');
        $H3= $this->input->post('valh3');
        $R6 = $this->input->post('val6');
        $R7 = $this->input->post('val7');
        $R8 = $this->input->post('val8');
        $R9 = $this->input->post('val9');
        $R10 = $this->input->post('val10');
        $R11 = $this->input->post('val11');
        $R12 = $this->input->post('val12');
        $R13 = $this->input->post('val13');
        $H4 = $this->input->post('valh4');
        $R14 = $this->input->post('val14');
        $R15 = $this->input->post('val15');
        $R16 = $this->input->post('val16');

        $data = $R1.",".$R2.",".$R3.",".$H1.",".$R4.",".$R5.",".$H2.",".$H3.",".$R6.",".$R7.",".$R8.",".$R9.",".$R10.",".$R11.",".$R12.",".$R13.",".$H4.",".$R14.",".$R15.",".$R16;
        $list = array($data);

        $file = fopen("./bin/pdw_table.csv","a");

        foreach ($list as $line)
        {
            fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
        }

        fclose($file);
        redirect('datacast_ctr');
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<head>

    <title> Datacast </title>
    <!-- css stylesheets -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>source/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>source/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>source/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plugins/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function() {
                $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                     $('.td1').toggle('show');
            });
         });

         function submit()
         {
             document.getElementById('add1').submit();
             return true;
         }

         function edit_submit()
         {
             document.getElementById('edit1').submit();
             return true;
         }

         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.btnEdit').editable();
         });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="row-fluid offset9">
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div id="navigation-menus">             
                           <div id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="span1" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                   <div class="menu-add">Add</div>
                           </div>               
                       </div>                   
                   </div>
               </div>
    </div>
            <div id="div1" class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="table-data">
                                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Field 1</th>
                        <th>Field 2</th>
                        <th>Field 3</th>
                        <th>Field 4</th>
                        <th>Field 5</th>
                        <th>Field 6</th>    
                        <th>Field 7</th>
                        <th>Field 8</th>
                        <th>Field 9</th>
                        <th>Field 10</th>
                        <th>Field 11</th>
                        <th>Field 12</th>                               
                        <th>Field 13</th>
                        <th>Field 14</th>
                        <th>Field 15</th>
                        <th>Field 16</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                                        <?php foreach($csvData as $field)
                                            {
                                        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 1']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 2']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 3']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 4']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 5']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 6']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 7']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 8']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 9']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 10']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 11']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 12']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 13']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 14']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 15']; ?></td>  
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 16']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><a class="btnEdit" onclick="edit();" style="cursor: pointer;">Edit</a> <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btnDelete">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <?php }?> 

                                    <form method="post" name="add1" id="add1" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/datacast_ctr/write_csv" autocomplete="off">
                                          <tr class="td1" id="td1" >  
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val3" id="val3"/></td>
                                                <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="valh1" id="valh1"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val4" id="val4"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val5" id="val5"/></td>
                                                <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="valh2" id="valh2"/></td>
                                                <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="valh3" id="valh3"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val6" id="val6"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val7" id="val7"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val8" id="val8"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val9" id="val9"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val10" id="val10"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val11" id="val11"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val12" id="val12"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val13" id="val13"/></td>
                                                <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="valh4" id="valh4"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val14" id="val14"/></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val15" id="val15"/> </td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="val16" id="val16"/></td>
                                                <td><a onclick="submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">Save</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </form>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Fetch the entire data, edit it like you want it to be and save the new data to the file.

Comment: should i need a new data file? Is it possible if i will save it in the same data file?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You could use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` if you are sure that it is your own file.

Comment: can you give me a sample code for that because i am a newbie in php - codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really simple example using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). It should not be used with big csv files and only is used to describe a possible method:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($filename);
$csv = explode("\n", $csvData);
$newData = array();
foreach($csv as $rowData) {
    $row = explode(";", $rowData);
    //change your data here
    $newData[] = implode(";", $row);
}
$newData = implode("\n", $newData);
file_put_contents($filename, $newData);
```

If you want to parse big csv files you can have a look at the examples that are provided [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Thank you, i will try it and get back for the result :)

Comment: hi @Tobias Kun i can't get the data in file_get_contents

$this->load->library('csvreader');

       $filePath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv';

       $data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);

       $this->load->view('datacast_view', $data);

that code is my CSV reader

Comment: I use this code to add data in CSV file 

$data = $R1.",".$R2.",".$R3.",".$H1.",".$R4.",".$R5.",".$H2.",".$H3.",".$R6.",".$R7.",".$R8.",".$R9.",".$R10.",".$R11.",".$R12.",".$R13.",".$H4.",".$R14.",".$R15.",".$R16;
        $list = array($data);

        $file = fopen("./bin/pdw_table.csv","a");

        foreach ($list as $line)
        {
            fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
        }

        fclose($file);
        redirect('datacast_ctr');

by the way i am using codeigniter

Comment: i have already update my question. You can see it above :) thank you :)

Comment: the above codes are all working.. I'm just thinking if what should i do with the edit and delete.

Comment: A database is not an option? If not IMO you have no other option to load the csv into memory, manipulate the data and save it back to the file.

Comment: Highly required to us to not use database and save it automatically into CSV file. What is an IMO?

Comment: save it back to the file is what i need but i don't know how.

Comment: `file_put_contents` will save the provided data to specified file. IMO = in my opinion.